# What is an efficient strategy for multiple threads posting jobs and waiting for response from a single thread?

Tags: java, concurrency

In java, what is an efficient solution to the following problem:

I have multiple threads (10-20 or so) generating jobs ("Job Creators"), and a single thread capable of performing them ("The worker"). Once a job creator has posted a job, it should wait for the job to finish, yielding no result other than "it's done", before it keeps going.

For sending the jobs to the worker thread, I think a ring buffer or similar standard fan-in setup would perhaps be a good approach? But for a Job Creator to find out that her job has been done, I'm not so sure..

The job creators could sleep, and the worker interrupt them when done.. Or each job creator could have an atomic boolean that it checks, and that the worker sets. I dunno, neither of those feel very nice. I'd like to do it with as few (none, if possible) locks as absolutely possible. So to be clear: What I'm looking for is speed, not necessarily simplicity.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Links to reading about concurrency strategies would also be very welcome!

Comment: Just use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`; use `submit` rather than `execute` and hold onto the `Future`. Call `Future.get` to wait until it completes.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the creators to wait until their submitted task is done if they don't care about the result? Seems a little fishy to me :3

Comment: @Brian They need to be guaranteed that the job was performed before they can start fiddling on their next job request.

Comment: Just do as @oldrinb said, it's simple and as good as it gets. I'm not sure what your concern about speed is, but you can't synchronize threads without locks - unless you want to spend processor cycles busy-waiting.

Comment: @Flavio Spending processor cycles busy-spinning is definitely an option, I know LMAX uses that rather than sleeping/taking locks, with good results.

Comment: @jakewins - spinning is an option, but it is usually a BAD option rather than a good one ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this. The *fastest* way would probably be to just use [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and a single-threaded executor.

```
private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void submitJob() {
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    executor.execute(new Job(semaphore));
    semaphore.acquire(); // Will block until semaphore.release() below
}
```

Then in the Job class:

```
public class Job implements Runnable {

    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public Job(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Perform task and run the actual job
        semaphore.release(); // Cues the submitter to continue at semaphore.acquire()
    }
}
```

`Semaphore` is decently fast, much faster than using `synchronized` blocks.

**Edit:** I should also note that this avoids a lot of overhead from `Future`, and so is probably also faster than the `Future` implementation suggested by others, but without testing it myself, I can't be sure.

Comment: Also... why not use `Condition`?

Comment: @oldrinb I'll see if I can come up with a performance test for this to see which is the fastest. Also, I simply forgot about `Condition`, and it would probably work a little better than `Semaphore`. I'll include it in my testing.

Comment: This looks really good, I'm gonna see if I can set up a benchmark as well for this tomorrow.

Comment: Semaphore and Future are both based on AQS so performance differences are likely to be negligible... Unless you have a concrete micro benchmark to support otherwise, and the future based code can be simpler to implement.

Comment: @StephenConnolly Their `Sync` implementations may both use `AbstractQueuedSyncronizer`, but the `Future` class has a bunch of overhead in addition to that, including thread status, which has to be updated by the `Executor` as the thread runs, and cancellability, which the `Executor` has to check. When it's not necessary to know the result and no extra info is needed, why have all the overhead if they use the same base mechanisms for their syncing? I'd imagine that this adds something that's not necessarily computationally negligible, I just have to test it (which I shall soon... hopefully) :)

Comment: Ensure you give the jvm enough time to optimise away the cruft... Most people making these choices forget that the jvm is very good at optimising. I have had java code run faster than hand tuned C code because it was able to optimise even further.

Comment: @StephenConnolly While the JVM may get rid of some cruft here, it can't change the object byte signature, at least not to my knowledge. With the semaphore approach, memory overhead should be lower, and the semaphore approach opens up to make the system garbage free later on. At just a few hundred thousand ops/s, adding just a few bytes of cruft to the heap in the innermost loop will have significant penalty. I agree though that the future-based approach is simpler (meaning most people should go for it). I'm looking for speed though.

Comment: @jakewins GC of short lived objects is faster than you think. Premature optimization is evil. Write the simplest thing that could possible work first. Then when the app is working profile and optimize. Optimizing before you have a functional app only delays development and may prove pointless in the long run. I wrote a Java based Audio Conferencing server that handled mixing for 100's of calls with the basic implementation which was (I thought) quite GC heavy... only after extensive profiling did I find the true hot-spots to get to nearly 1000 calls... The C++ optimized code was 4000 calls

Comment: BTW that C++ optimized code was the result of nearly 20 years optimization and a dedicated media stack by some very smart guys... my little java stack only handled the basic codec and was just for testing some SIP and RTP based stuff... sadly I no longer have the code, being left with my former employers and probably lost or unknown to the people who remain... My point is that you seem to be applying C++ style thinking to Java code... and the JVM is not C++ ;-)

Comment: The problem with this approach is it tries to solve a problem that is already solved with Futures.  You create, arguably, the same amount of GC data but lose nice functionality like error propagation you get with Futures.  The argument that this performs better is like trying to optimize one one-thousandth of a percent.

Answer (score 1):

I would favour a single threaded executor service and just submit the worker instances to that (getting a future for the result). You can then get() the future to both block until the result is available and get the result

```
public class TheWorker {
  private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

  public Result work(Job job) {
    return service.submit(new Callable<Result>(){
      ...
    }).get()
  }

}
```